# Error in for loop to calculate a percentage

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am trying below code with a loop to calculate the percentage of # of rows in df of delivery company that is closed and open, but I get an error for the line `num_total = lead_df.Status[0]` this should work to give me # rows just like the code a few lines prior but is giving me error with a `KeyError: 0`

```
leads = ['Closed','Open']
    max_status = None
    max_percent = None
    for lead in leads:
        df_overall = df[(df['Status']== lead)]
        num_overall = df_overall.Status[0]
        lead_df = df[(df['Grubhub']== True)]
        num_total = lead_df.Status[0]
        percentage_overall = num_overall / num_total
       
        
        if max_status is None: 
            
            
            
            print(lead, percentage_overall)
```

Where the df looks like:

```
 Status | Grubhub 
  Closed    True
   Open     True
   Open     False
```

I dont know what I am missing in the num_total line as it should work when run `df[(df['Grubhub']== True)]` in a separate cell it gives me 400 rows, thanks!

Comment: Howw working `num_overall = df_overall.Status.iat[0]` ?

Comment: if I add .iat[0] to both num overall and num total it says TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with why you'd want to use `.Status`, but you can try this instead.

`num_total = len(lead_df)`

Comment: sorry I added how the df looks or at least the two important columns from the df, status is a column name

Comment: @Chris90 Okay gotcha -  The key error might be from the index not being reset on `lead_df` as well. Even if you reset the index and then filtered down DataFrames like you did, then `lead_df.Status.iloc[0]` would return `Closed`, not the number of rows present.

Comment: Thanks, why does it work 2 lines above in my code when I run df_overall.Status[0]?

Comment: when I replace the num_total code with len(lead_df) it gives me an error for the code before it that says num_overall = df_overall.Status[0]

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand ... do you mind sending over the actual error output?